# Maintaining Key values when converting from Map to List ImmutableJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I'm having a utility function that converts a map into a list. It is supposed to still have the key values attached to it, but for some reason it doesn't. Rather I need to read of by index, of which is not really useful for my use case. Do someone know how to preserve keys when I transfer from a map? Here's my source

```
function getMetaStateArray(metaStateArrayOrObject) {
  let metaStateArray;

  if (metaStateArrayOrObject && Immutable.Map.isMap(metaStateArrayOrObject)) {
    metaStateArray = metaStateArrayOrObject.toList();
  }
  else {
    metaStateArray = metaStateArrayOrObject;
  }

  return metaStateArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by making a list Wrapper around my map, while doing `List.of()` inside the wrapper, so the map inside won't turn into a regular array:

```
metaStateArray = List(List.of(metaStateArrayOrObject));
```